# Creating a CloudSQL instance with terraform and custom lightweight machine

Tags: terraform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

To create an sql database instance you need to specify the tier in the form

```
db-custom-<CPUs>-<Memory_in_MB>
```

It ends up setting up an standard machine type. How can I specify a lightweight type?

Answer (score 0):

it's legacy format (e.g., db-f1-micro, db-n1-standard-1, ...).

current machine type(lightweight, standard and high memory) is just guide line. see below.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance#machine-types